# Как из SQL-запроса достать данные в глобальные переменные

Tags: javascript, sql, база-данных, select, global-variables

Я решил поизучать работу с базами данных SQL через JavaScript.
У меня есть база данныъ TESTDB и таблица в ней profile.
Я хотел с помощью select доставать кол-во строк и из этого получать id нового пользователя.
Сначала подключил базу данных:

```
const mysql=require('mysql');
//config
const connection=mysql.createConnection({
    host:"localhost",
    user:"pmauser",
    database:"TESTDB",
    password:"password_here"
    
});
```

После чего с помощью SELECT-запроса нашел новый id:

```
const sql = `SELECT * FROM profile`;
var new_id;
connection.query(sql, function(err, results) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    const res=results;
    new_id=res.length+1;
});
```

Тут все работает правильно, и если добавить в функцию `console.log(new_id)`, то все выводит правильно. Но если в главной программе вызвать `console.log(new_id)`, то либо выводит ошибку, что нет такой функции, либо выводит "undefined".
Я так понял, что new_id - локальная переменная и ее надо сделать глобальной. Я пробовал `global[new_id]=res.length` - не помогло. Что делать?

Comment: Может быть стоит объявить new_id ДО запроса?)

Comment: Вам нужно разобраться с асинхронностью в JavaScript. Например, почитайте этот вопрос с ответами, всё равно вас скорее всего адресуют туда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/

Comment: @radar4ick Я объвил и так - просто не выложил. Кстати вопрос: почему если сделать два вывода new_id -  в запросе и после - выводит сначала undefined, а потом значение? Должно же быть в обратном порядке.

Comment: сначала выполнился синхронный код, где ваша переменная undefined, потом пришел ответ от запроса и выполнилось присвоение в коллбэке функции, и получилось значение

Comment: @radar4ick что сделать, чтобы они выводились в нормальном порядке и что делать с глобализацией?

Comment: Сделать функцию асинхронной и дождаться её выполнения async/await, а потому уже обращаться к этой переменной

Comment: @radar4ick сделал: (async () => {
connection.query(sql, await.function(err, results) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    const res=results;
    new_id=res.length+1;
    console.log(new_id)
});
})();
Но выводит, что . после await - unexpected token. Что я не так сделал?

Comment: Переменная `new_id` объявлена с помощью `var` внутри функции. Поэтому она локальная для этой функции. Либо объявите её снаружи, либо уберите var.

Comment: `res.length+1` - нельзя так делать. Потому что после удаления части данных из таблицы вы можете получить потом айдишник, совпадающий с уже имеющимся.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov у меня так и есть - объявлена в главной программе, в функции без var(см. прошлые комментарии). А насчет res.length - как может быть совпадающий id, если грубо говоря res.length - кол-во строк в базе данных, а значит когда мы добовляем новую строку, то она будет c id=номеру строки

Comment: А что произойдёт, когда вы удалите хотя бы одну (или несколько) строк из таблицы?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Аааа понял. Спасибо, что объснили. С этим как-нибудь разберусь потом. Можете подсказать, как должна выглядеть эта часть моей программы, чтобы действия выполнялись синхронно (поочереди), а то, как видите в предыдущих комментариях у меня это не получается. Буду очень признателен.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалась проблема в асинхронном программировании. Требуется написать так:

```
const sql = `SELECT * FROM profile`;
var new_id;

connection.query(sql, async function(err, results) {
    if(err) console.log(await err);
    const res=results;
    new_id=res.length+1;
});
```